# sizeof struct gcc compile success, but g++ compile failed

Tags: c++, struct, g++

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test{
    int n;
    struct next{
        int x;
    }level[];
}test;

int main()
{
    printf(" %d \n", sizeof(struct next));
    return 0;
}
```

I have a code called test.c like this. 
It's copied from a c source code. When i compile it with Gcc , it successes. 
But when i compile it with g++ , the compiler complain :

```
test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c:12:37: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘main()::next’
  printf(" %d \n", sizeof(struct next));
```

I have search for a long time, but no result. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: G++ is the C++ frontend. If you want C++ code, use the correct extension and the correct grammar. C and C++ are **different** languages (your code looks like C, though and is not compatible with C++).

Comment: So is your question why does this C code not compile as C++?

Comment: Note that not all valid C programs are valid C++ programs. You seem to expect the inverse.

Comment: Well, the detail that is worth mentioning here is that by default `gcc` determines the language by analyzing file extension, meaning that `gcc` compiles `.c` files as C. Meanwhile, `g++` always compiles as C++, regardless of the file extension, meaning that this `.c` file is compiled as C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for your reply. My question is how can i compile this code correctly in C++ ?

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for your reply. Do you mean extern "C" ? I have tried this , but it's still error.Is there other solutions?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes. I want to find the solution to use this code in C++.

Comment: @unwind Thank you.Do you mean there is no solution to use this code in c++?

Comment: @AnT Thank you for your patient reply. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ are different languages with different rules. This is one such example where C++ is not strictly a superset of C.

In C, nested structs are members of the same enclosing namespace. So `sizeof(struct next)` refers to the previously fully declared type `next` which has a member `x`, whose size is `sizeof(int)`. This is well-formed code.

In C++, nested classes are members of the enclosing class - so `struct next` does *not* refer to `test::next` and instead is a forward declaration of a local type `next` within the scope of `main()`. This type is incomplete, so you cannot apply `sizeof()` to it.

When you compile a file that ends in `.c` with gcc, you're compiling the code as a C program, so it succeeds. When you compile with g++, you're compiling the code as a C++ program, hence the error.

Comment: `struct next{ int x; }level[];` is also not valid C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, but it doesn't really matter for the purposes of this question - the issue in the question is the difference in nested class scoping in C and C++. Also both gcc and clang allow it as an extension.

Comment: @Barry Thank you. Now i know the difference between c struct and c++ struct. Do you have any suggestion of using c code like this question in c++ ?

Comment: @杜智超 yes, my suggestion is: don't use it at all

Answer (score 1):

If you change code like

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test{
    int n;
    struct next{
        int x;
    }level[];
};

int main()
{
    printf(" %d \n", (int)sizeof(test::next));
    return 0;
}
```

It would works for C++. I compile it with g++ 4.9